Web Routing in Angular 17
I have a routing file written as below:
  {
    path: "student",
    component: StudentComponent,
    canActivate: [authenticationGuard],
    data: {
        role: "student",
      },
    children: [
      {
        path: "information",
        component: InformationComponent,
        data: {
          name: "Information",
        }
      },
      {
        path: "submission",
        component: SubmissionComponent,
        data: {
          name: "Submission",
        }
      },
      {
        path: "seminar-invitation",
        component: SeminarInvitationComponent,
        data: {
          name: 'Seminar',
        }
      },
    ],
  }

and in an html file
      <mat-nav-list>
        @for (item of routes(); track item) {
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="[item.path]" [routerLinkActive]="['router-is-active']" class="block">{{
          item.data.name }}</a>
        }
      </mat-nav-list>

I am trying to create blocks of options which direct users to the desired page, I cant seem to get there. Every time a block is clicked, the url says http://localhost:3000/information (for example), instead of http://localhost:3000/student/information.
I have tried using [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" but the error still exists. Can someone enlight me on this? I am using Angular 17 and I want the site to take me to /student/information.
I also want each block to have a different icon. How can I achieve so? Thanks in advance.

When can specify that the route is a relative route, how do do this is by specifying ./
<mat-nav-list>
    @for (item of routes(); track item) {
    <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['./', item.path]" [routerLinkActive]="['router-is-active']" class="block">{{
      item.data.name }}</a>
    }
</mat-nav-list>

If that does not work, you can convert the routelink to a click event which calls a method navigateTab
navigateTab(path:string) {

    this.router.navigate([path], {
         relativeTo: this.activatedRoute // to make the navigation happen relative to the current route!
    })
}

In the html it will be
<mat-nav-list>
    @for (item of routes(); track item) {
    <a mat-list-item (click)="navigateTab(item.path)" [routerLinkActive]="['router-is-active']" class="block">{{
      item.data.name }}</a>
    }
</mat-nav-list>


Hi, I have tried your answers but it does not works :(
